# Calling python function from shell script

Tags: python, shell

Can some one help me with the syntax, how to call 'x' function from a shell script. The challenge here is, from shell script need to pass a,b dynamically.

your suggestion greatly appreciated.

Python Code:

```
def x(a,b):
    '''x(a,b) --> [a,b]'''
    return [a,b]

def add(a,b):
    '''add(a,b) --> a+b'''
    return a+b

def test():
    '''test code for all modules'''
    print "testing x..."
    print x(1,2)
    print x('a','b')
    print x([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
    print "testing add..."
    print add(1,2)
    print add('a','b')
    print add([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
    return
```

Comment: Wow. Ultimate search before you post fail.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, but that answer is old and not Python3 compliant

Comment: @JohnLaRooy this isn't a Python3 question, and `$ python` on *nix should always run python2. If you'd like to update the answer, do so on the duplicate.

Comment: @AdamSmith, Arch linux already defaults to python3 and  Ubuntu 16.04 is planning to move away from python2.., PEP0394 says "for the time being..."

Comment: @JohnLaRooy is that so? Awesome! Python2 has been a long-rotting corpse as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you save the file `foo.py`, you can run this from the shell

```
python -c "import foo; print(foo.x(1, 2))"
```

The result can be read from stdout.

Comment: thanks for response.. But I need to pass the param dynamically . Like python -c "import foo; print(foo.x(${var1}, ${var2}))"

Comment: So do that. What is stopping you?

Comment: This is not working on our Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11, please help me to identify the alternative